# Переключить активный класс по клику ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Не могу додуматсья как при клике добавить активный класс к элементу `<tr></tr>`

**Попытки:**
**1**.

> Я попыталсья написать таким образом

```
clickEventHandler = id => {
     const activeState = this.state.active;
     this.setState({active:!activeState});
};
```

И добавить компоненту такой код

```
<ListTable addedName={this.state.active ? 'active': null} />
```

Но при таком подходе добавляетсья класс active каждому кликнутому tr то есть они не переключаютсья.

**Попытка: 2**

Я попыталсья добавить события к самому компоненту   `ListTable` а это в свою очередь добавило при клике всем `tr` элементам класс `active`

Структура кода:

У меня получаетсья взять `id` кликнутого элемента (код внизу) но не могу додуматсья как сделать переключение  класса `active` при  клике.

Компонент **ListTable**

```
const ListTable = props => {
    return (
        <tr className={props.addedName} onClick={props.actived}>
            <th scope="row">{props.id}</th>
            <td className="text-left">{props.name}</td>
            <td>{props.count}</td>
            <td>{props.price}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Компонент **Table**

```
const Table = props => {
    return (
        <table className="table mt-3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">№</th>
                    <th className="text-left" scope="col">Names</th>
                    <th scope="col">Count</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {props.tableLists}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

И Основной контейнер

```
clickEventHandler = id => {
        console.log(id);
};
render(){
         const lists = this.state.mainData.map((items) => {
            return <ListTable key={items.id} 
                              id={items.id}
                              name={items.username}
                              count={items.phone}
                              price={items.website} 
                              actived={() => this.clickEventHandler(items.id)} 
                              addedName={this.state.active ? 'active': null} />

         })
         return (
            <div style={styles.container}>
                <Table tableLists={lists} />
            </div>
         )
     }
```

Также state основного компонента

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       mainData:[],
       active:false
   }
}
```

Данные загружаютсья через **axios** все перемещаетсья после загрузки  в `state.mainData` потом от туда беретсья в `ListTable`

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в state хранить id текущей активной строки, если одновременно активной может быть только одна строка

Основной компонент:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mainData:[],
        activeTab:-1
    }
}
clickEventHandler = id => {
    this.setState({
        activeTab:id
    })
};
render(){
    const lists = this.state.mainData.map((items) => {
        return <ListTable key={items.id} 
        id={items.id}
        name={items.username}
        count={items.phone}
        price={items.website} 
        actived={() => this.clickEventHandler(items.id)} 
        addedName={this.state.activeTab===item.id ? "active" : null} />

    })
    return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
    <Table tableLists={lists} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

И `ListTable`

```
const ListTable = props => {
    return (
        <tr className={props.addedName} onClick={props.actived}>
        <th scope="row">{props.id}</th>
        <td className="text-left">{props.name}</td>
        <td>{props.count}</td>
        <td>{props.price}</td>
        </tr>
        )
    }
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное